# How to run command NSLog(@"Alert display...") immidiately when alert Local Notifications show?

Tags: iphone, notifications, local, alert

How to run command NSLog(@"Alert display...") immidiately when alert Local Notifications show?...I'm creating a alarm clock in iphone, I want to play a music at that time (at alert Local Notifications display)! I'm going to use AVPlayer to play music form ipod library in iphone! But I can't do it. Can you help me! Thanks!

Comment: so do you want to do a "`NSLog`" or do you want to play music when a local notification fires into your app?

Comment: Actually, I want to play music when a local notifications fires,It play music and alert notification display is same time!

Comment: You can use soundname property of UILocalNotification and give your custom sounds also

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute your code when LocalNotification pops up if your app is in background and suspended. What you can do is assign you music file to soundName property, but note that your sound must not be longer then 30 secs. Here is the code:

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.soundName = @"yourMusicFile.caf";
```

Of course, if your app isn't suspended you can play music using AVAudioPlayer...